# How to revert a shell command? Overwritten the "pwd" command

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, terminal

After typing "pwd" in shell you normally get the path to the current working directory. However, if you type "pwd()" instead, you get a message [function>] after which you can type anything (eg: echo hi; ls -laR).

Now executing the "pwd" command will no longer print the current working directory, but instead it will execute the user input every time.

My question is, how do I revert this behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to restart Bash?
If that doesn't work you can use `unset -f pwd` remove the function.

More info at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions

Answer (score 0):

by doing pwd(), you are creating a shell function.

Get rid of it by:

```
unset pwd
```

Comment: For some reason unset pwd doesn't seem to restore functionality. Worked after restarting Bash though